# How to embedd qr codes over existing image?

Tags: qr-code

[Sample image of qr code embedded over given image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LL7s6.png)

So i am working with qr codes in my project and I need to superimpose my qr code over an image. Example image is attached. I generated this from an online qr code generator. Which libraries can i use to generate such such images either in a web application or a mobile application?

Answer (score 0):

You can use any GD library provided by any programming language. What you're looking for is ***`Watermarking`***. Some examples are:

**C#**

You can follow this [article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2927/Creating-a-Watermarked-Photograph-with-GDI-for-NET) using GDI for .NET.

**PHP**

Example directly from [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/image.examples-watermark.php).

```php
<?php
// Load the stamp and the photo to apply the watermark to
$stamp = imagecreatefrompng('stamp.png');
$im = imagecreatefromjpeg('photo.jpeg');

// Set the margins for the stamp and get the height/width of the stamp image
$marge_right = 10;
$marge_bottom = 10;
$sx = imagesx($stamp);
$sy = imagesy($stamp);

// Copy the stamp image onto our photo using the margin offsets and the photo 
// width to calculate positioning of the stamp. 
imagecopy($im, $stamp, imagesx($im) - $sx - $marge_right, imagesy($im) - $sy - $marge_bottom, 0, 0, imagesx($stamp), imagesy($stamp));

// Output and free memory
header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```